# Is it possible to use a ViewGroup for Empty ListView?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a `ListActivity` whose layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent" style="@style/FullWidth.NoteList" />
  <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/empty" style="@style/FillParent">
    <ImageView style="@style/NoNotesImage" />
    <TextView android:text="@string/no_notes" style="@style/Shadowed.NoNotesText" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/note_add" android:text="@string/note_add" style="@style/Shadowed.Button.Blue"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The styles relevant here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style name="Shadowed">
  <item name="android:shadowDx">1.1</item>
  <item name="android:shadowDy">1.1</item>
  <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.1</item>
</style>
<style name="NoNotesImage">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
  <item name="android:layout_marginTop">80.5dip</item>
  <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dip</item>
  <item name="android:src">@drawable/bg_no_notes</item>
</style>
<style name="Shadowed.NoNotesText">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/no_notes_text</item>
  <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/no_notes_shadow</item>
</style>
<style name="FillParent">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
</style>
```

However, my empty list view consist only of the `ImageView` listed first inside the nested `LinearLayout`.

This seems like a reasonable thing to do but I don't completely understand Android's layout rules yet.

Comment: It's definitely possible to use an empty ViewGroup as the empty View, bu it's hard to tell what might be going wrong because of your heavy use of styles (thus making it impossible to tell how your XML is actually laid out).  Maybe you could show us what styles you're using?  Also, styles aren't typically used on such basic attributes as layout_width and layout_height.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added the styles I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to take a shot in the dark.  The LinearLayout should work but I'm guessing that you're accidentally pushing Views off the screen.  I bet that LinearLayout's android:orientation is accidentally being set to "horizontal" and the ImageView's layout_width is "fill_parent"; doing that will block the TextView and the Button.  You probably just need to change the LinearLayout's android:orientation to "vertical" and it will work as expected.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid. Thanks! Adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to both `LinearLayout` views fixed it right up.